# How to fix generateDS error: "Can't find file TObject.xsd referenced in <_io.BufferedReader name='some_name.xsd'>."

Tags: python, xsd, python-generateds

I am using generateDS (http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html) to create python classes by some XSD, to create different XML files with python then. It works properly with some simple XSD files, but when I try the one I need, it gives me an error "process_includes.SchemaIOError: Can't find file TObject.xsd referenced in <_io.BufferedReader name='shipporder.xsd'>.".

Actually I have no idea how to fix it.

```
python generateDS.py -o lib_test.py  shipporder.xsd
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. Can help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286548/parse-an-xml-with-generateds-and-external-references?noredirect=1#comment126011615_71286548

Comment: I do not remember exactly, but in my case it was something wrong with filenames

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue. In your case, it's caused by missing file `TObject.xsd`.

You may wonder where `TObject.xsd` comes? it supposes to be found in your `shipporder.xsd`, something like

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="TObject.xsd" ...
```

`generateDS` load all XSD not only indicated in arguments but also XSD files that are imported. So make sure `TObject.xsd` is existed.

---

The actual problem is `generateDS` didn't give an understandable error message.